# Selenium Java - Cannot Load URL in Microsoft Edge version 18

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

My Edge Version:  18.18362
OS Build Version: 18.18362

Installed Edge Driver with the command `DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0`

Selenium Java code to Initialize browser :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

The browser is getting opened but the url is not loading.

There are 4 paths where MicrosoftWebDriver.exe is present after installing with DISM.exe. Which among this should I use in Initializing?

1. C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-webdriver-server-components_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.18362.1_none_cf827c8a6da82156
2. C:\Windows\SysWOW64
3. C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-webdriver-server-components_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.18362.1_none_c52dd23839475f5b
4. C:\Windows\System32

I have also enabled developer mode in windows.

Still URL is not loading in EDGE. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace.

Comment: There is no errors thrown. The browser is getting opened, But URL is not getting loaded

Comment: Post the code for navigating to the url.

Comment: its just driver.get("url");

Comment: The edge was working fine with my local PC(EDGE Version is 17.something) with the same code. But after deploying, the automation script is running in a windows virtual node in which th EDGE version is 18.18362. So I added driver as a feature since the version is 18. Now I am stuck here, The URL is not loading.

Comment: Nov 04, 2019 1:48:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
The new session could not be created. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'TEST-PC', ip: 'xx.xx.xxx.xx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver

Comment: I have created a sample using the 4 paths, they all work well on my machine(using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.387.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362 version), please navigate to "Internet  properties"
Click on the "Security" tab
Make sure that each of the four zones (Internet, Local intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites) are all the same value (the Enable Protected Mode option).

Comment: I tried. Its not working for me.

Comment: Please check the import Java Selenium package version, which version are you using?

Comment: Selenium 2.0 and Selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1